# U-SQL FROM parameter

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I was wondering if anyone could help me understand what the below code means and what is the purpose of using it.

```
DECLARE @INPUT_BatchID string = "9035";
DECLARE @BatchID int? = (int?) int.Parse(@INPUT_BatchID);

@dataset1 = 
SELECT col1,col2,col3 
FROM Table AS T

@dataset2 =
SELECT col1,col2,col3
FROM Table2(@dataset1, 0, 20, @BatchID)
```

---

TVF Code below:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [Table2](
@baseValues TABLE(ENT_MBR_NM string, [ALS] string,
[NC] string, [DELD] string,
PRNT_MBR_NM string, HIER_LVL int,
GEO_ENT_GENERATION_ID int?, [PATH] string,
RGN_CD string, GLB_GRP string),
@CurrentIteration int = 0,
@MaxIterations int = 20,
@BatchID int? = -1)
RETURNS @result TABLE(ENT_MBR_NM string, [ALS]
string, [NC] string, [DELD]string, PRNT_MBR_NM
string, HIER_LVL int, GEO_ENT_GENERATION_ID int?,
[PATH]string, RGN_CD string, GLB_GRP string) AS

BEGIN
DECLARE @cont1 string = "EMEA";
DECLARE @cont2 string = "EUROPE";
DECLARE @cont3 string = "TOTAL CHINA";
DECLARE @cont4 string = "ASIA PACIFIC";
DECLARE @cont5 string = "UNITED STATES";
DECLARE @cont6 string = "OTHER AMERICAS";
DECLARE @cont7 string = "TOTAL AMERICAS";
DECLARE @cont8 string = "MIDDLE EAST/AFRICA";
DECLARE @cont9 string = "OTHER ASIA PACIFIC";
IF (@CurrentIteration >= @MaxIterations) THEN
@result = SELECT * FROM @baseValues;
ELSE
@nextLevel =
    SELECT A.ENT_MBR_NM,
           A.[ALS],
           A.[NC],
           A.[DELD],
           A.PRNT_MBR_NM,
           T.HIER_LVL + 1 AS HIER_LVL,
           A.GEO_ENT_GENERATION_ID,
           T.[PATH] + " | " + (A.PRNT_MBR_NM ?? "*") AS [PATH],
           A.ENT_MBR_NM.Trim().ToUpper() IN (@cont5, @cont6, @cont2, @cont8, @cont3, @cont9) ? A.ENT_MBR_NM : T.RGN_CD AS RGN_CD,
           A.ENT_MBR_NM.Trim().ToUpper() IN (@cont7, @cont1, @cont4) ? A.ENT_MBR_NM : T.GLB_GRP AS GLB_GRP
    FROM @baseValues AS T 
         INNER JOIN
            [Wz].[Fc].[DH_FCS_GEO_ENT] AS A 
         ON T.ENT_MBR_NM == A.PRNT_MBR_NM
    WHERE A.PartitionID == @BatchID.Value;
    
@baseValues =
    SELECT *
    FROM @baseValues
    UNION ALL
    SELECT *
    FROM @nextLevel;
     
@result = [Table2](@baseValues, @CurrentIteration + 1, @MaxIterations, @BatchID);
END;
END;
```

This code takes lot of execution time which I want to reduce but I am not sure what the code part (@dataset1, 0, 20, @BatchID) in the @dataset2 means and the use of this.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Table2` is most likely a [table valued function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/u-sql/ddl/functions/table-valued-functions)(tvf): a function that, optionally, takes some parameters (like your example) and returns a set of records.

Somewhere the `Table2` function is defined in your script or a reference.

The same applies to `Table`. It might be a tvf as well.

Note: it has been a while since I last saw a question using u-sql. You know already [the service is being retired](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/migrate-to-azure-synapse-analytics/)?

Comment: Thanks a lot @Peter Bons, this makes sense. Also would there be any suggestion you would have to optimize this code?

Comment: I think the troublesome code is in that function as the code you show is pretty straightforward and not complex in terms of the query

Comment: Hi @Peter Bons, The TV function too looks fairly simple with a couple of select statement and UNION ALL being used in one of a dataset. Attaching code in next comment.

Comment: Added TVF below

Comment: Is that the same TVF? The one you attached is called TVF while the one called is called Table2.

Comment: @Priyanka2304 it is better to add any new code to the existing question by editing it. Otherwise the information is scattered through the question and answer(s).

Comment: @Priyanka2304 Looking again at the question, I am wondering what `Tabel` is. It might be another TVF. Can you try to locate it in the code and post the content.

Comment: @PeterBons, I did not realize that the names of the function are different before posting it here. I did edit the code to change the name. Fixed the TVF code now.

Comment: @Priyanka2304 so now the question remains: what is the definition of `Table`? Is it another TVF or a real dataset and if so, what is its source?

Comment: Table is a real dataset. One weird thing I noticed was when I took backup of the TVF (just with TVF name change and the internal logic remains same) and ran the original script pointing to this new TVF, the job completed in under 10 mins where the original job took over an hour to complete. Not sure what could be the reason behind this. Would you have any comments on this?

Comment: I suppose it might be caused by different parameter values? Other than that I have no clue.

Comment: @Priyanka2304 feel free to [accept any answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it was of any help to you. If it isn't, feel free to ask for details.